# ASP.NET flexible webform, with dynamic sub-parts

Tags: asp.net, iframe, webforms

- I have an asp.net webform, divided into many "blocs", for example 10
- I also have, for example, 3 different kind of "sub-page", each one composed of  many controls
- depending on a database, each one of the 10 "blocs" will display a different type of "sub-page"
- for example : bloc1=subpage3 ; bloc2=subpage1; etc....

The only way I found is to create a main webform composed of 10 iframes, and to create 3 other webforms, and to assign these to the SRC attribute of the iframes.

***Is there a "better" way?***

Comment: Have you considered user controls for that?

Comment: What are the advantages/disadvantages ?